# Why does "to wire" mean to trick?

Tags: expressions, idioms, slang

*A Collection of College Words & Customs* written by Benjamin Homer Hall in 1856 defines a "wire" as a trick and I'm curious to know if it is of any relation to a magician using invisible wire to trick his audience? Any thoughts?

Comment: Seems likely that your explanation is apt, both in relation to the stage and to seances. Floating apparitions and knocking sounds have been controlled by wire.

Comment: ...and I believe that kind of stage trickery was very much in vogue back then.

Answer (score 2):

Wire-pulling is associated with trickery:
Wire-pulling is defined as *political manipulation* in **The American slang dictionary** 1891 and [Wire-puller in the political sense is 1848, American English, on the image of pulling the wires that work a puppet.](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=wire&allowed_in_frame=0)

but a good magician needs to be artful in 'picking your pocket', as well as, adding items to your person, and a wire is a ***thief with long fingers, expert at picking ladies' pockets***.  It is reasonable that 'to wire' was 'stolen' from thieves

Comment: Do you happen to have a reference for "a wire" being "a thief with long fingers"? It's a cool term.